# Python call function again if incorrect input

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python, I am just wondering what the best way to do this (very simple question):

I have a function that prompts the user to select an option, if the option they entered is not valid it will call the function again:

```
def choose_colour():
    print "Select colour:"
    print "1. Red"
    print "2. Blue"
    print "3. Green"
    selection = raw_input()
```

Initially I had an if statement comparing the input and IF it was an incorrect input I would call the function again within itself. Which is not practical and wrong.

```
def choose_colour():
    print "Select colour:"
    print "1. Red"
    print "2. Blue"
    print "3. Green"
    selection = raw_input()

    if selection == "1":
         colour = "Red"
    elif selection == "2":
         colour = "Blue"
    elif selection == "3":
         colour = "Green"
    else:
         print "Please select, 1, 2 or 3"
         choose_colour()
```

Edit:

This works but I prefer the loop solution.

```
def set_TPL_colour():
    print "Enter TPL colour value:"
    print "1. WHITE"
    print "2. GREEN"
    print "3. AMBER"
    print "4. RED"
    print ">>>",
    option = raw_input()
    if option == "1":
        tpl_colour = "WHITE"
        return tpl_colour
    elif option == "2":
        tpl_colour = "GREEN"
        return tpl_colour
    elif option == "3":
        tpl_colour = "AMBER"
        return tpl_colour
    elif option == "4":
        tpl_colour = "RED"
        return tpl_colour
    else:
        print "ERROR incorrect option selection"
        tpl_colour = set_TPL_colour()
        return tpl_colour
```

Comment: It's not necessarily *not practical and wrong.* If `choose_colour`should return the selected color just use `return ...` instead of `colour = ...` and then at the end modify it as `return choose_colour()`

Comment: This function exits without printing anything out if selection is in `['1', '2', '3']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the function again, just put it in a while loop and reassign the variable if input is not valid:

```
def choose_colour():
    print "Select colour:"
    print "1. Red"
    print "2. Blue"
    print "3. Green"
    selection = raw_input()
    while selection not in ("1","2","3"):
        print "Please choose a valid option"
        selection = raw_input()
    if selection == "1":
        colour = "Red"
    elif selection == "2":
        colour = "Blue"
    elif selection == "3":
        colour = "Green"
```

A cleaner version:

```
def choose_colour():
    colourChoices = {"1":"Red", "2":"Blue", "3":"Green"}
    selection = raw_input("Select colour:\n 1. Red\n 2. Blue\n 3. Green")
    while !colourChoices[selection]:
        print "Please enter valid data"
        selection = raw_input("Select colour:\n 1. Red\n 2. Blue\n 3. Green")
    colour = colourChoices[selection]
```

Comment: This is a cleaner solution that what I was trying. Thanks it makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary , Example -

```
def choose_colour():
    print "Select colour:"
    print "1. Red"
    print "2. Blue"
    print "3. Green"
    colordict = {"1":"Red" , "2":"Blue", "3":"Green"}
    selection = raw_input()
    ret = colordict.get(selection)
    if not ret:
        return choose_colour()
    return ret
```

You can also do while loop -

```
def choose_colour():
    colordict = {"1":"Red" , "2":"Blue", "3":"Green"}
    ret = None
    while not ret:
        print "Select colour:"
        print "1. Red"
        print "2. Blue"
        print "3. Green"
        selection = raw_input()
        ret = colordict.get(selection)
    return ret
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> def choose_colour():
...     print "Select colour:"
...     print "1. Red"
...     print "2. Blue"
...     print "3. Green"
...     colordict = {"1":"Red" , "2":"Blue", "3":"Green"}
...     selection = raw_input()
...     ret = colordict.get(selection)
...     if not ret:
...         return choose_colour()
...     return ret
...
>>> choose_colour()
Select colour:
1. Red
2. Blue
3. Green
5
Select colour:
1. Red
2. Blue
3. Green
2
'Blue'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
input = raw_input()
while not_valid(input):
   print_options()
   input = raw_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple way. First of all, use my Input() function and control errors. Also, you can put here a long length list and this program can handle it.

```
# If your input value is only a number then use "Value.isdigit() == False".
# If you need an input that is a text, you should remove "Value.isdigit() == False".
def Input(Message):
    Value = None
    while Value == None or Value.isdigit() == False:
        try:        
            Value = str(input(Message)).strip()
        except InputError:
            Value = None
    return Value

# Your answer:
def choose_colour():
    # Your colors list
    Colors = ["Red", "Blue", "Green"]
    # Print your menu
    print("Select colour:")        
    for Item in Colors:
        print(str(Colors.index(Item) + 1) + ". " + Item)
    print("")
    Choice = -1
    # If user entered an incorrect answer, ask your question again
    while Choice <=0 or Choice > len(Colors):
        Choice = int(Input("Your choice: "))
    # Print user choice
    print("You choosed " + Colors[Choice - 1])

choose_colour()
```